# Trying to set up a server to receive OSC input, Keep getting this error when I run Script from python-osc

Tags: python, python-3.x, osc

I'm new to python so not sure what I am missing to get this running.

Here is the code from python-osc:

```
from pythonosc.osc_server import AsyncIOOSCUDPServer
from pythonosc.dispatcher import Dispatcher
import asyncio


def filter_handler(address, *args):
    print(f"{address}: {args}")


dispatcher = Dispatcher()
dispatcher.map("/filter", filter_handler)

ip = "127.0.0.1"
port = 1337

server = AsyncIOOSCUDPServer((ip, port), dispatcher, asyncio.get_event_loop())
server.serve()
```

please help. I have no idea what I'm doing, I just want to set up a live osc stream from a Muse EEG to an iPad streaming with/through UDP to my Mac. From there, it'd be nice to analyse the data, but one problem at a time.